# Unable to GET file using jquery (Ajax) on IE 11 or Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am trying to download a file using jquery's ajax. I need to download the file, and then have it save to the user's device. The reason i do it this way is because i need to add authentication to the download request.
I have managed to get the following code and it works on <s>normal browsers</s> Chrome and Firefox.
This is the code:

```
            $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            xhrFields: {
                responseType: 'blob'
            },
            //contentType: "application/octet-stream",
            processData: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            beforeSend: function (xhr)
            {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth.accessToken);
            },
            dataType: 'binary'

        }).done(..).fail(..).always(..);
```

None of the Done, Fail or always functions are called, ever. IE just sits there showing "pending" in the network request.
I've tried with/without content-type.

On my last attempt, IE actually crashed. Edge sometimes just closes quietly.
I'm testing downloading a 1GB file on my local dev machine.

As mentioned, it works in other browsers.

My fallback is to create a  URL with token info as query parameters, but this is not good practice.

I'm open to either a solution to this problem or a different way to download the files with authentication built in.

Comment: Does it work with a small file (eg 1000 bytes or so)?  I'm not surprised IE crashes trying to download a 1GB file directly into memory.

Comment: also Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, uncheck "Do not save encrypted files to disk"